# FlorientR/laravel-gentelella: npm install --global bower gulp fails

Tags: npm, gulp, bower, laravel-5.3, gentelella

I want to use the following framework: 
https://github.com/FlorientR/laravel-gentelella

But when I follow the installation guide I need to run the following commands:

```
php artisan key:generate
npm install --global bower gulp
npm install
bower install
gulp
```

The first command works fine, but: `npm install --global bower gulp` fails. It gives the following error:

```
> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\har-valid
ator\src\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����������������
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\req
uest\lib\har.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\no
de_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--global" "bower" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

> npm ERR! C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\
har-validator\src\index.js:1
npm ERR! (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { �������������
���
npm ERR!                                                               ^
npm ERR! Unexpected token ILLEGAL
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

The package.json contains:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Do you guys see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled NodeJs. That was the problem..